# Trazer dados automaticamente com Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho dois *models* `cliente.rb` e `atendimento.rb`, ambos já com suas *associations*. Quando vou gerar um novo atendimento consigo através do `collection_select` selecionar o nome do cliente, o problema e que eu gostaria de na hora de selecionar o cliente outros campos como endereço, telefone também viessem automaticamente para meu formulário, por exemplo: no meu cadastro de cliente eu tenho nome, telefone, endereço, etc. Já no meu cadastro de atendimento eu tenho o nome do cliente (busco através do `collection_select`), telefone do cliente (quero que seja preenchido automaticamente ao selecionar o cliente), endereço, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte, vamos por parte:

1. Opte por escrever seu código em inglês, pois você irá enfrentar problemas com design. Por exemplo: o model **Distribuidor** no plural ficará assim: **Distribuidors**. O que lhe obrigará escrever coisas como: `empresa.distribuidors.each {}`.
2. Para Fazer esse preenchimento automático você deve seguir os seguintes passos:

   a) Crie uma endpoint que responderá ao método **GET** em formato json, algo como: `/private_api/clientes.json`, note que você deve observar questões de autenticação.

   b) Por javascript ao selecionar um cliente no seu formulário de atendimento, ele deve disparar uma chamada para o endpoint e assim pegar os dados e preencher o formulário. seria algo assim em jQuery:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#atendimento_customer_id').change(function() {
       $.getJSON('/private_api/clientes.json', function(data) {  
         $('.nome-do-field').val(date.nomeDoField)
       })
     })         
   })
   ```